# Código com erro no Switch Case

Tags: java, switch

Tenho que fazer o seguinte exercício:

> Fazer um programa em Java que solicita o total gasto pelo cliente de
>   uma loja, imprime as opções de pagamento, solicita a opção desejada e
>   imprime o valor total das prestações (se houverem).
>
> 1) Opção: a vista com 10% de desconto
>
> 2) Opção: em duas vezes (preço da etiqueta)
>
> 3) Opção: de 3 até 10 vezes com 3% de juros ao mês (somente para compras
>   acima de R$ 100,00).  Use o comando Switch.

Estou com dificuldade de encontrar onde estou errando no código abaixo:

O erro está quando chamo o switch.

```
package Prova_A;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exe_02 {

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    int op() {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op;

        System.out.println("*****Modo de Pagamento*****");
        System.out.println("1 - Á Vista");
        System.out.println("2 - 2 Vezes");
        System.out.println("3 - 3 Vezes");

        op = ler.nextInt();
        System.out.println("*******************************\n");
        return (op);
    }

    float aVista(float vlr) {
        System.out.println("Total R$: " + vlr);
        System.out.println("Total a pagar R$: " + vlr * 0.9);

        return (0);
    }

    float duasVezes(float vlr) {
        System.out.println("Total R$: " + vlr);
        System.out.println("Total a pagar R$: " + vlr / 2);

        return (0);
    }

    float tresVezes(float vlr) {

        int parcelas;

        System.out.println("Total R$: " + vlr);

        do {

            System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de parcelas :\n");
            parcelas = ler.nextInt();

        } while ((parcelas > 10) || (parcelas < 3));

        System.out.println("Parcelas de R$:\n " + parcelas + (vlr * 1.03) / parcelas);

        return (0);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        float vlrCompra;
        int opcao;

        System.out.println("Informe o total da compra: \n");
        vlrCompra = ler1.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("***************************\n");

        switch(op){

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Pagamento a vista: \n");
                vlrCompra = ler.nextFloat();
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Não estou vendo onde você leu o "op" do seu switch

Comment: Gustavo, estou tentando ler aqui  int op() { no começo do código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há alguns erros a serem corrigidos.

> #### Primeiro

O método *main* é método estático, para poder acessar alguma variável ou método os mesmos também deverão ser estáticos.

Para isso altere seus métodos para serem estáticos

```
static int op()
// ... e assim por diante.
```

> #### Segundo

O *switch* esta recebendo uma variável que não existe, para corrigir pode fazer de dois jeitos.

1. Chamar o método `op` direto.

   ```
   switch(op()) //..
   ```
2. Criar a variável `op`

   ```
   int op = op();
   switch(op) //..
   ```

> Podes ver funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/LyU2)
>
> **Obs:** não sou nenhum profissional, pode haver outras maneiras de resolver.

Comment: Wéllingthon, muito obrigado era isso mesmo... ainda estou aprendendo essa sintax java...